# Generating symbol matrices that satisfy regular expressions row- and column-wise

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, regular-expressions, strings, concurrency

I have a program that fills a matrix of size N with characters such that all words formed by each row satisfy one regular expression, and all the words formed by each column satisfies a second one.

For example, say I have $N=3$, regular expression $c^*ab^*$ for rows and $b^*ac^*$ for columns. A solution would be

$\qquad\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & b \\
  c & a & b \\
  c & c & a
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm trying to find an algorithm that is faster than the brute force one. I am further looking for a way to split this algorithm in independent processes so I can use parallelism to decrease the time needed to reach a solution.

Comment: Since language described by regex might have infinite number of words, I suspect you either work with only finite language OR you only list some first words generated by regex ordered in someway. It would be good to clarify on that.

Comment: @D.W. Better now, isn't it?

Comment: One simple approach might be to express this as an instance of SAT and apply a SAT solver.  There's no reason to expect this to work well for large $N$, but it's so easy to try you could try implementing it and see how well it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea that may still take exponential time in $N$ but is polynomial in the (length of) the regular expressions.

Consider strings over the shared alphabet $\Sigma$ of length $N^2$; each such string represents an $N \times N$ matrix stored row-wise. We insert a separation character $\$ \not\in \Sigma$ between rows.

We will now construct a finite automaton the accepts exactly the set of such strings that fulfill your two regular expressions.

Let $r$ resp. $c$ be the row resp. column regular expression

1. Clearly, $r_N = (r \cap \Sigma^N\$)^{N-1}(r \cap \Sigma^N)$ matches all matrices that match $r$ in every row. Transform $r_N$ into an NFA $A_{r,N}$.
2. Denote with $A^{(i)}_{c,N}$ the automaton that matches only every $N$-th 
   input symbol (ignoring $\$$) against $c$, starting with the $i$-th. 
   I will leave the construction as an exercise; suffice to say that we 
   need at most $N$ copies of $A_c$.

   Now, $A_{c,N} = A^{(1)}_{c,N} \cap \dots A^{(N)}_{c,N}$ accepts the set of all matrices each column of which matches $c$.
3. The automaton $A_{r,c,N} = A_{r,N} \cap A_{c,N}$ accepts all the matrices 
   you want.
4. A simple graph traversal finds an accepting path in $A_{r,c,N}$ finds 
   a solution matrix, if any.

The blowup in size is mild (i.e. at most a factor $N^2$) for all constructions but the intersections; these multiply sizes, so we may look at a factor $2^N$ for automaton size.

That's still way better than checking all $\Sigma^{N^2}$ possible matrices.